# PHP: Where to put rsort?

Tags: php, directory-listing

```
$count = 0;

if ($handle = opendir('./arkiv/')) {
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
            $count++;
            print("<a href=\"arkiv/".$file."\">".basename($file, ".php")."</a><br />\n");
        }
    }
    echo '<br /><br /><a href=".">Tilbake</a>';
    closedir($handle);
}
```

This is the code I'm using, and I'm trying to figure out where to but 'rsort', but this is very new to me, can anyone help me?

Comment: First you need to put all the results into an array, then use `rsort` on the array, and then loop through the array and print out the values.

Comment: why you want to use rsort ... ? to sort the file names .. ?

Comment: `rsort` reverses an array, you need to use it against an array, so you should traverse the directory first to `push` the file names into an array

Comment: @ new_developer: Yes, it lists all previous newsletters, and I would like the newest to be on top.

Comment: @ h2ooooooo: Aha, I read something about that, but could you please help me write it, because I have no idea where to place it inside the code. Or write it, for that matter :/

Comment: @LotusH: That makes sense. Do you think you could be of even more assistance and help me with it?
(I really hate being one of those people who want others to write their code, but PHP is so new to me)

Comment: @StianKarlsen try my post and see it is what you want .. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible use can be like

```
$count = 0;
         $fileArray = array();
         if ($handle = opendir('./arkiv/')) 
         {
            while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) 
            {
               if ($file != "." && $file != "..") 
               {  
                  $count++;
                  $fileArray[] = $file; 

               }
            }
            rsort($fileArray);
            foreach($fileArray as $file)
            {
               print("<a href=\"arkiv/".$file."\">".basename($file, ".php")."</a><br />\n");
            }

            echo '<br /><br /><a href=".">Tilbake</a>';
            closedir($handle);
         }
```

Give it a try ....
GOOD LUCK !!!

Comment: Haha! Magnificent! I will learn from this, I give you my word on that! Thank you very much.
And a big thanks to all of you others who took the time to answer me, I am very grateful.

Comment: @StianKarlsen definately .. even I will learn something new .. :)